# DBPedia skipping some articles

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a Sparql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title ?title ?year 
WHERE {
?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
?film_title rdfs:label ?title .
?film_title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?year .
FILTER (LANG(?title)='en')
} ORDER BY DESC(?year) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

I have used descending order for release year. But some movies are missing, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady_in_the_Car_with_Glasses_and_a_Gun_(2015_film). It was released on 5th Aug 2015, but it is still not in the list.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're limiting to 100 films.  Were there fewer than 100 films in 2015 and 2016 so far?  Why do you expect to get all the films in 2015?

Comment: I tried setting offset to 100 to check next results and it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that DBpedia has an entry for that film.  If the article was created recently enough, it might not be in the latest DBpedia.

Comment: The article was added in august 2015. :(

Comment: Alright, so I see movies are listed in `dbo:Work` instead of `dbo:Film`. :(